# How to move overall project settings from database to code?

Tags: c#, design, architecture

I need to move two database tables data into code. These tables consist of some data settings (30 and 1000 lines accordingly). This movement of data is a first step towards bigger refactoring. As a result i would like to get rid of two tables, have this data stored somewhere in code.

I can not do:

- use application settings because of it is not one project or even one solution to use this data
- use another database (noSql)

The problems i am facing at the moment are:

- what tool to use to move data from DB to code (moving 1000 lines manually scares me)
- no idea how to store these settings (readonly lists, dictionaries or something)
- where to store these settings to have access from any project

Thank you for your time and ideas.

EDIT: I need to move data from database because this data is static that means that it will not be changed much in future. This data also consists of UI settings that is not a good idea to store it in DB. From the other hand we need to reduce the number of database calls. And this data is a good candidate to be moved out of the database.

Comment: I do not think, that being a good idea.

Comment: @ThomasJunk why so?

Comment: "we need to reduce the number of database calls"  Why? Are you reducing the load on the database or is this something that is a problem within the app itself?  Why can't you use a text file?

Comment: As the question was first posted,  the initial intention seemed to be: instead of using a DB simply hard code everything. The obvious consequence is redeployment for every configuration change, which is from my perspective no good idea. Besides I do not get, what is won by storing data in an external file instead of a Database. More: to reduce load, the app could read the configuration once at startup - no further load.

Answer (score 3):

> what tool to use to move data from DB to code

Whatever tool you have available to execute arbitrary queries and pipe them into a text file or other tabular data format. An SQL query tool (probably the one your DB vendor provides you with), MS Excel, a tool you write by yourself, pick your choice.

> no idea how to store these settings (readonly lists, dictionaries or something)

Whatever format for tabular data you prefer. XML, JSON, CSV, a spreadsheet format of your choice, a generated code file. This depends on the complexity of the data, the extensibility you need, your requirements for maintenance of the settings data, and your personal preferences.

> where to store these settings to have access from any project

Write a class which can load the data from whereever the file is stored, and make that class available to any project which needs it. If the class is inside of some DLL, it is simple to make the data file an embedded resource of that DLL, so your class can load the data from there. But if you want to deploy the data file in a manner the end user can easily look into it, deploy it just side-by-side to your application.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know which technology you are using and what sort of data do you have (XML columns or something exotic like that), but if you come from .NET world and it's simple data we're talking about, have you considered [SQL Server compact edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) or [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite)?

For SQL CE, it's small, fast, can be stored in a project that you can link to other projects, you have most of the possibilities of a database, you can use ORM like Entity Framework to bind to it and you can still separate your data and code.

The project where you have SQL CE can be used for all of the manipulation of your parameters.

[ErikEJ](http://erikej.blogspot.de/) is SQL CE master and has [tools](https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox) that can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

If these are truly app settings that are configured regularly or even occasionally I strongly suggest leaving them in database tables where they can be more easily updated. Having this data stored in a single place is the only way to really ensure when a value is changed that it propagated everywhere. If you move these into an external file format or embed them in a dll its much more likely projects will make their own local copies that greatly increases the difficulty of updating values everywhere and its much harder to keep track of the values without essentially rewriting SQL functionality for your custom format.

You are better off creating a public API that all your projects have access to thus isolating database access and management to a single project. You could also implement a caching system here if database calls are the concern.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new project with the sole purpose of providing access to these parameters. It could then be built as a DLL and linked into as many different projects and solutions as you wish.

I agree that moving 1000 lines manually sounds like a lot of opportunity for human error. Once you've decided on the structure of the file you will be using for storing the parameters in code, I would suggest writing a utility program with the sole function of pulling those parameters from the database and writing them in the desired file format.

Comment: As i can assume, storing in file is a recommended option. Writing tool that moves data from db to file is not a problem. Just need to figure out possible approaches. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my recommendation, you can store the lookup data in the external **XML formatted file**. This would help you to build the proper structure of the data in the XML format. This will give you better readability and maintenance over the period of time.

Then read this file XML data from the code and **build a strongly-typed business object**. And use the object in the code as when required into your project. If the data is in the form of key-value pairs, then you can also build a HashTable object in the code. A strongly-typed business object can give the benefit of IDE intellisense also.

Since its a lookup data & will not undergo rapid or frequent changes, its performance can be raised by utilizing the concept of file dependency caching feature also. In your application, you can read the XML file once and prepare the strongly-typed business object and hook this object with cache dependency linked with the external file. The cache object will remain intact until someone touches the XML file and makes changes to it.

In MS SQL Server, you can use FOR XML and build out the desired XML structure to copy the data from the database. Then you can copy the XML into an external file.